# Magnify Image within extension pages dialog?

Tags: xpages

I have an image within an extension pages dialog box that I would like to magnify when the mouse pans over the image.

I found this bit of js and css:

http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/mojomagnify/

It works great if the image is on the main page.  But if the image is within an extension pages dialog box, the dialog box is popped up, and the mouse is moved over the image, the mouse pointer does not change to the cross hairs and the image is not magnified.

Any theories as to why?    Or now to fix it?

Any image magnifies that would work within a dialog box?

Comment: what are you trying to do, stretch and shrink the original image or display a new image that is larger then then you hover the image? you could try the dojo lightbox if you want to display a larger image on mouse over the image. it is really easy to implement, you can try it out at http://www.intrapages.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog is probably loaded and triggered dynamically and using partial refresh  so your JavaScript is loaded before the dialog box is available.

The onClientLoad events are only triggered when the xpage loads. Not on partial refreshes

What you need to do is to make sure your JavaScript loads after the dialog is available. This can be done using another JavaScript that listens to partial refresh events found here

http://dontpanic82.blogspot.se/2010/01/xpages-hijackingpublishing-partial.html